# Extra period appended to the context while surface shift

Tags: actions-on-google

When there is a surface shift (actions.intent.NEW_SURFACE), if the context property is ended by a punctuation other than a period, such as ? ! etc, Google adds an additional period.

Answer (score 1):

When you said context property, do you mean context name? You can learn more about the rules of context naming in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-manage#name). Punctuations like ?! are not valid.

Comment: No, not context name. Content of the context. See below JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

In the Hub, it will display "... so we can keep talking!.". See extra period after !.
{
"expectUserResponse": true,
"expectedInputs": [
{`enter code here`
"possibleIntents": [
{
"inputValueData": {
"capabilities": [
"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
],
"context": "Ok, to continue, I'll need you to look at a screen.  Make sure your notifications are on, so we can keep talking!",
"notificationTitle": "Click this notification to continue",
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.NewSurfaceValueSpec"
},
"intent": "actions.intent.NEW_SURFACE"
}
]
}
],
"isInSandbox": false
}